# TCL script - how many bytes of data will be received?

Tags: networking, ns2

I recently had my midterm in Computer Networking, and one of the questions was:

"How many bytes of data will be received at node n2 at the end of this simulaton? (Packet size is specified in bytes)"

```
set ns [new Simulator]
set n0 [$ns node]
set n1 [$ns node]
set n2 [$ns node]
$ns duplex-link $n0 $n1 1Mb 20ms DropTail
$ns duplex-link $n1 $n2 1Mb 20ms DropTail
set udp0 [new Agent/UDP]
$ns attach-agent $n0 $udp0
set cbr0 [new Application/Traffic/CBR]
$cbr0 set packetSize_ 500
$cbr0 set interval_ 0.010
$cbr0 attach-agent $udp0
set sink0 [new Agent/Null]
$ns attach-agent $n2 $sink0
$ns connect $udp0 $sink0
$ns at 1.0 "$cbr0 start"
$ns at 4.0 "$cbr0 stop"
$ns at 5.0 "finish"
```

I asked for the correct answer from my professor, but he went through the solution in class and I missed that one, so I was wondering if any of you had a solution for me. I know how to calculate the end-to-end delay, but I don't know what to do here. I'm looking for a calculation, not a command.

Comment: tell your professor to stop giving you questions on ns2 and upgrade to ns3 already :)

Comment: @HamedTemsah: If it bothers you so much, _you_ write to his professor to encourage him to do all that effort to convert his existing course. Generally speaking, students have very little control over what software they have to learn as part of their courses (beyond the basic control of whether they take the course at all).

Comment: @DonalFellows :) yeah that is correct, students don't have much control on course material, here they have converted to NS3 since a year ago. I see you have no problem with TCL though, well done